# Should I make pipe() in my service if I have done the one in my component.ts

Tags: angular

I'm little bit confused as I have seen some people write `pipe()` as in `service` as in `component` where they invoke own `service`
I have a service
**my-service.ts**

```
getList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api}/list`);
  }
```

And I have a component which uses this service
**component.ts**

```
this.myService.getList().pipe(
      catchError(() => of(null)),
      finalize(() => this.loading = false)
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {if(res) this.list = res }
```

As you can see I have done `pipe(catchError(),finalize())` in my **component.ts** .Should I make the same inside my **service.ts** ?
Something like that
**my-service.ts**

```
getList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.api}/list`).pipe(...other same code);
      }
```

It looks like double work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your use case. If you only want to affect the data in the component, only pipe it there. If you want to affect the data used everywhere, do it in the service. If you want to do one thing everywhere and another thing in your component, do it differently per each place. Just FYI - `pipe` just means you are doing something to the data after you have received it

Answer (score 3):

`.pipe()` is a rxjs method that enables you to chain operators from `rxjs/operators` like `map(), filter(), ...`. It is said in the documentation that the purpose of the pipe method is to make the chaining of this method more human readable [Piping section](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

The question you have to ask yourself is whether you think the logic will be shared accross your app, or is it specific to your component ?

- In the first case I would use `.pipe()` in my service
- Otherwise you can use it in your component. One advantages of using
  `.pipe()` with rxjs operators in your component is that you can easily unsubscribe from the observables using operators like `.pipe(takeUntil(timer(1000))`, avoiding this way memory leaks.